# Parsing Jira Table Format with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, jira

i'm trying to write a parser in python for Jira Table Format to put the data in a list. The following sample is the basis. I want to extract the the data of the table of each subelement as a list which in the next step should be handled by an another function...see below. I just started with programming and actually i really don't know how to do it and i would be glad if you can give me any ideas how to handle that.

First: Convert jira table data in a list:

```
|| tablehead 1 ||  tablehead 2 || tablehead 3 || tablehead 4|| tablehead5 ||
| text1 | text1 | text1 | text1 | text1 | --> subelement 1 --> list 1
| text2 | text2 | text2 | text2 | text2 | --> subelement 2 --> list 2
...more subelements |text|...
```

Returned list can look like:

```
["text1", "text1", "text1", "text1", "text1"] list1
["text2", "text2", "text2", "text2", "text2"] list2
```

...etc.

Secondly another function takes all the lists and do stuff...
Thought something like:

```
for list in lists:
    do sth with content of every list
...etc
```

@Elodin i hope this helps 
thanks in advance

haselere

Comment: Could you please add your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question, but if you want to convert your table into a list, you could try using `.split("|")` which would convert your text into a list at every | character.

E.g.

`"| hi | lol | me".split("|")` would return `["hi", "lol", "me"]`.

I hope this helps.

P.S. Could you please clarify your question, as in, what do you want your return list to look like?